# How to change cursor shape depending on VI mode in Bash?

Tags: bash, terminal, xterm

I have the following line in my .bashrc:

```
set -o vi
```

And I want my cursor to have a pipe shape when I am in insert mode and a block shape when I am in command mode, like what I would have in Vim if I placed the following in my .vimrc:

```
let &t_SI = "\e[6 q"
let &t_SR = "\e[4 q"
let &t_EI = "\e[2 q"
```

Except in this case I want to have the equivalent behavior on the command line.

I found a partial answer to my question here -
 https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/22527/change-cursor-shape-or-color-to-indicate-vi-mode-in-bash - written by @gogolb.

Here is the answer, copied:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Script "kmtest.sh"

TEST=`bind -v | awk '/keymap/ {print $NF}'`
if [ "$TEST" = 'vi-insert' ]; then
    echo -ne "\033]12;Green\007"
else
    echo -ne "\033]12;Red\007"
fi

export PS1="\u@\h \$(kmtest.sh)> "
```

Unfortunately, though, as explained in the answer, the example script only changes the cursor shape after a carriage return, whereas, what I want is for the cursor shape to change when I hit <Esc> (i.e. when I change mode).

I am on Linux running the native terminal app, with Bash 4.4.7 and my $TERM variable set to xterm-256color. Also, I do not know if tmux has any effect on what I am asking for, but I, ideally, would like the solution to work both within and exterior to tmux sessions.

**SOLUTION**

I ended up discovering the answer to this question myself, which I describe here in another question I posted:

[How to correctly link patched GNU readline library to all existing programs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45136948/how-to-correctly-link-patched-gnu-readline-library-to-all-existing-programs)

Don't worry, the solution does not require any patching. ;)

Answer (score 49, accepted):

**SOLUTION:**

*I am posting my answer to my own question here as recommended.*

This solution works for Bash 4.4+, since, starting with that version of Bash, version 7.0 of the GNU readline library is used, which includes the necessary additions of the `vi-cmd-mode-string` and `vi-ins-mode-string` variables.

These variables can be set as follows in your *.inputrc* file in order to achieve the functionality I described above:

```
set show-mode-in-prompt on
set vi-cmd-mode-string "\1\e[2 q\2"
set vi-ins-mode-string "\1\e[6 q\2"
```

---

**EXPLANATION:**

*For those who are actually interested in how the above solution works.*

These two variables, `vi-cmd-mode-string` and `vi-ins-mode-string`, are printed to your terminal along with the command prompt in order to provide a sort of visual indicator as to which mode you are currently in (i.e. command mode vs. insert mode).

The defaults for these two variables are "**(cmd)**" and "**(ins)**" for command and insert modes, respectively. So if you were to just leave them as the defaults and had a command prompt of, say, `PS1='>>>'`, then your prompt would look like the following:

- Command mode:

  ```
    (cmd) >>>
  ```
- Insert mode:

  ```
    (ins) >>>
  ```

According to the man-page for *readline* (see below), you can also specify non-printable characters, such as terminal control sequences, by embedding the sequences between the \1 and \2 escape characters.

```
vi-cmd-mode-string ((cmd))
       This  string  is  displayed immediately before the last line of the primary prompt when vi editing mode is active and in command mode.  The value is expanded like a key binding, so the
       standard set of meta- and control prefixes and backslash escape sequences is available.  Use the \1 and \2 escapes to begin and end sequences of non-printing characters, which  can  be
       used to embed a terminal control sequence into the mode string.
vi-ins-mode-string ((ins))
       This  string is displayed immediately before the last line of the primary prompt when vi editing mode is active and in insertion mode.  The value is expanded like a key binding, so the
       standard set of meta- and control prefixes and backslash escape sequences is available.  Use the \1 and \2 escapes to begin and end sequences of non-printing characters, which  can  be
       used to embed a terminal control sequence into the mode string.
```

Therefore, in my above solution, I am embedding the terminal control sequences, `\e[2 q` (make the cursor a vertical bar) and `\e[6 q` (make the cursor a pipe), between these \1 and \2 escape characters, resulting in my cursor having the shape of a vertical bar while in command mode and a pipe shape while in insert mode.

Comment: Cool, thanks for that! However, I have a problem with this solution: When I put those 3 lines into `.inputrc`, the cursor within vim (like, when I'm editing a file) changes to a pipe symbol as well.  I don't want that - any idea how I can prevent that from happening?

Comment: I don't have that issue for some reason. I'm using `NextJump/jarvis` from Github, and within my `vimrc.local` file, I've written the `let &t_SI = "\e[6 q"`, etc. commands (see the original problem description)... maybe adding that will fix your issues.

Comment: Thanks, it does, indeed.

Comment: This works in Git Bash on Windows but cursors are not blinking, do you know how to enable blinking?

Comment: If you want blinking you can try using the blinking versions of the above control sequences. E.g. blinking block cursor = "\e[1 q", blinking underline cursor = "\e[3 q", blinking vertical bar cursor = "\e[5 q".

Answer (score 5):

This is awesome. I want to add that in addition to adjusting the cursor, it is still possible to have a textual mode state message as well. This code works:

```
set show-mode-in-prompt on
set vi-cmd-mode-string "\1\e[2 q\2cmd"
set vi-ins-mode-string "\1\e[6 q\2ins"
```

`cmd` and `ins` will show up on the left of the prompt based on the mode.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to reset your cursor to normal before your other programs run, then you can use the environment variable `PS0`. From `man bash`:

> The value of this parameter is expanded (see PROMPING below) and displayed by interactive shells after reading a command and before the command is executed.

Setting PS0 with this command will cause it to restore the cursor to a non-blinking block:

```
PS0="\e[2 q"
```

Answer (score 2):

The answer by Alan Barnett re:

> Setting PS0 with this command will cause it to restore the cursor to a non-blinking block:

> `PS0="\e[2 q"`

Solved my Vim issue, but instead of `PS0="\e[2 q"`, I wrote `PS0="\e[2 q\2"`. Alan's answer somehow added a `]` on my terminal output of any command.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I'm using, yes unicode. The only downside is that when you're not running X server the unicode is borked! :-)

```
 set show-mode-in-prompt on
 set vi-ins-mode-string \1\e[34;1m\2└──[ins] \1\e[0m\2
 set vi-cmd-mode-string \1\e[33;1m\2└──[ cmd] \1\e[0m\2
```